# Mango Queries on a value that doesn't exist

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, couchdb-mango

I want to be able to search my documents for every item that either doesn't have the item `hidden` in it, or if it does, only grab it if it's not equal to `true`. Is this possible?

I have the following selection and I am getting a bad query error.

```
selector: {
  hidden: {$in: [null, false]}
}
```

For example:

**I want these to be returned**

```
{_id: "1", hidden: false, name: "John" }
{_id: "2", name: "Jim" }
```

**This not to be returned**

```
{_id: "3", hidden: true, name: "James" }
```

Comment: what's wrong with the @Juanjo Rodriguez answer

Answer (score 6):

You can try with an or expression that checks the existence of the 'hidden' attribute

```
 {
  "selector": {
    "$or": [
      {
        "hidden": false
      },
      {
        "hidden": {
          "$exists": false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```